# How to change the function of the back button in the flutter app bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, appbar

How can I change the function of the back button in de app bar? So I want to go to the home page when you click on the back button how can I make this work?

```
 appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: const BackButton(
          color: Color(0xFFFD879A),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onPressed` to your `leading`:

```
leading: BackButton(
  color: Color(0xFFFD879A),
  onPressed: () {
    // do your navigate here

    print("back click");
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0,
    leading: const BackButton(
      color: Color(0xFFFD879A),
      onPressed: () {
          // execute this on pressed...
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: The const does need to be removed or i will get an error. but thank you very much for helping i made it work because of you help :)